# Transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and ran into a problem. Let's say I have a database of a bank which contains a category named accounts. I have id number 1 who has 1000 dollars and id number 2 who has 700 dollars. I want to make a transaction between them in 1 go. I've tried do the following:

```
update accounts
set balance = balance + 100 
where id = 2; 

set balance = balnce - 100 
where id = 3
```

What happens is the account number 2 looses 100 dollars but account number 3 gets nothing. How can I do such a thing in 1 go to ensure there wouldn't be any transaction in between?

Thank you

Comment: By "transaction sql" I suspect you mean T-SQL ?  Otherwise, tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one step:

```
update accounts
    set balance = (case when id = 2 then balance + 100 
                        when id = 3 then balance - 100
                        else balance
                   end)
    where id in (2, 3);
```

This is ANSI-standard syntax and most (if not all) databases should execute it "all-or-nothing" -- that is, either both updates take effect or neither.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that this is only a "transfer" if both rows are guaranteed to exist in the database -- otherwise money will appear from nowhere, or disappear into a black hole. (Of course, a real table with financial transactions would be a bit more complicated anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use transactions. Transactions are not an easy thing to learn and might take some time so I suggest reading about them from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql). Specially the ACID properties of relational databases.

For SQL Server, the basic steps are:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION -- Start your transaction here

    /* 
        You can do these 2 operations on the same statement in this case but I
        believe you want to learn the concept
    */

    update accounts
    set balance = balance + 100
    where id = 2

    update accounts
    set balance = balance - 100
    where id = 3

    -- Do other operations like INSERTS, DELETES, etc.

    COMMIT -- You apply your changes here. From this point it will be visible to other users and will be persisted.

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH -- If something went wrong...

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 -- ... and the transaction is still open
        ROLLBACK -- revert all the operations done from the point of "BEGIN TRANSACTION" statement onwards

    RAISERROR('Something went horribly wrong!', 15, 1)

END CATCH
```